# NeuralNet in C# Single output converting to multiple output c# dummy

Tags: c#, neural-network

I'm currently learning neural nets and stumbled across different sources and different codes all good however i found one code which found interesting and want to adapt it for various things such as OCR and that stuff. I am relatively new to C sharp and i would like some help on what i can do to make this code to my use. Basically this code adopts one output and I want that i can add several output neurons. My main problem is that i managed to adapt it to work with multiple outputs however then i found it impossible for me to test the network i.e First im training giving the network with the inputs and expected outputs. Then i just give the network an input string . The problem is that the Class Pattern is only accepts 3 parameters. How can i tell it/ work so that i can train with 3 parameters but then test only giving the string which i need to identify after that generalization is done ?? This is parts of the code which i am using for training -- this code is not mine just that its clear i am just using it for testing..

So testing-- this is being called

```
Activate(new Pattern(values, _inputDims)));
```

and Pattern method is this one --

```
private double[] _inputs;
private double _output; 

public Pattern(string value, int inputSize)
{
    string[] line = value.Split(',');
    if (line.Length - 1 != inputSize)
        throw new Exception("Input does not match network configuration");
    _inputs = new double[inputSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
    {
        _inputs[i] = double.Parse(line[i]);
    }
    _output = double.Parse(line[inputSize]);
}
```

so i want that the Pattern method accepts also outputSize however it must be able to do the testing when i just pass the value and input dimensions. Honestly i don't know what i can do I've already spent many time looking for all available options.

Comment: Full code which as i stated is not mine can be found on the following website - http://dynamicnotions.blogspot.com/2008/09/training-neural-networks-using-back.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional parameter to the pattern constructor. 
Pattern ( string value, int inputSize,  int outputSize = 1)